# Find the Orthogonal Projection of f onto g. Use the inner product in C[a,b]

Tags: linear-algebra

$C[-\pi, \pi],   f(x)=x$ and $g(x)= \cos 2x$
I am having a difficulties integrating this function. I dont know where I am messing up.
Please help me :D

Comment: and I don't know, what you mean? Maybe $\int_{-\pi}^\pi x\cos 2x dx$? This is $0$, do you know why$

Comment: well idk latex but I will show u the formula

Comment: (<f,g>)/(<g,g>)g

Comment: so <f,g> is what u have showed but i don't get know how to integrate that function

Comment: ohh i see. ya I get it now soit orthogonal already ok thanks @draks

Comment: @Sarah For the good of mankind and all that is sacred, please spell "you" as "you" and not "u". Note also that "i" should be capitalized as "I". Furthermore, since "Dont" is a contraction, please consider writing it as "Don't". Finally, although I know that "idk" is an abbreviation for "I don't know", I'm not so sure non-native speakers of English would realize that.

Comment: haha ok. I guess I this site isn't meant for me @3sphere

Comment: @Sarah I did not intend to imply that, only that a reasonable effort at grammatical correctness is appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad, if I could help.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Sorry about that.@3Sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three approaches for calculating $\int_{-\pi}^\pi x\cos 2x$. These are only hints, as this is a homework problem:

1. Use integration by parts, by defining $f(x)=x,\ g(x)=\cos 2x$.
2. Use the fact that the integrand is an **odd function** of $x$. What is the integral of an odd function on a segment that is symmetric around $0$?
3. Ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos%282x%29+x) and click "show steps".

Comment: Thanks @yohBS That was helpful